# How to send data to angular 2 http services

Tags: angular

I have an array of url which I need to send as the http service url path and generate the result based on the response type. Can anybody please tell how should I proceed.

Comment: Have you considered to make your question shorter? The last sentence could be removed. You could also try without whitespaces :p. Honestly, please provide more details about what you try to accomplish, what you have tried, and where you failed.

Comment: Hi Gunter, Thanks for your quick update. I have modified the above question here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271016/how-to-send-data-in-http-service-using-angular-2

Comment: You could have edited your question instead of creating a new one.