# How to send data in http service using angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of urls which I need to send as the http service url path and generate the result based on the response type. the example array is as below.

```
this.urlArray = ["www.test.com","www.test2.com"];
```

I iterate over the array and generate div and will send the url to http service as parameter and based on the request type like "time-out", success and error will change the div color. Can anybody please tell how should I proceed.

Comment: What have you tried?
Is the problem iterating over the array, or just basic $http usage in Angular2?

Comment: Problem is I need to send the url text to the http service as parameter.

Comment: Please check this  https://plnkr.co/edit/rxtAgu3PqoNkV90vBSEX?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

From https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

```
  addHero (name: string): Observable<Hero> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.heroesUrl, /*{ name }*/ this.urlArray, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```